# Bad request Flask

Tags: flask

I'm new to Flask and i'm trying to build my own flask app. I cannot figure out what cause this error.

> 400 Bad Request
>
> The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
> Here is my python code :

```
@app.route('/upload1', methods=['POST'] )
def upload1():
    mysql.connection.autocommit(on=True)
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    f = request.files['inputFile']
    r = pd.read_csv(f, sep=',')
    for it in r.iterrows():
       cur.execute('INSERT INTO users(user_name, pass, name, role_id) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)', it[1])

    cur.close()
    flash('Import Success', 'success')
    return redirect(url_for('admin'))
```

admin.html

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Admin <small>Welcome {{session.username}}</small></h1>
    <form action="/upload1" method="POST">
        <button name="upload1" type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: if not requiring pure flask, you can use wtforms which made file upload easier using form with file field.

Answer (score 1):

`f = request.files['inputFile']`

I'm not sure if this is the cause of the issue, but it looks like you're trying to read a file submitted with an HTTP POST, but your form content type is not correct. Add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` as an attribute to your HTML form. In addition, it looks like you're missing a place to upload the [file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) inside of the form.

```html
<form action="/upload1" method="POST">
<!-- Should become -->
<form action="/upload1" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<!-- ...and add a file input... -->
<input type="file" name="inputFile"> <!-- note that the name attribute matches the existing python code -->
```

If this attribute isn't included, the web browser will default to a Content-Type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which does not allow for file uploads.

Enabling Flask's debug mode is a good way to get more detailed information on errors. You can do that by modifying your `app.run()` statement to include the debug parameter, for example:

```py
app.run(debug=True)
```

Providing the specific exception thrown by Flask with the debug mode enabled will better help us understand the underlying cause of the issue. Hope this helps.

Comment: true, form must send correct content type, otherwise there are issues with input.

Comment: I added enctype in form element and nothing changed

Comment: @HungPham Are you able to enable debugging and paste the exception & traceback thrown by Flask? This should explicitly tell you why Flask doesn't like the incoming request.